# DD4T and Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, dd4t

There are no Tridion 2013 SP1 files in the trunk yet of the DD4T codebase, but will the 2013 files work with SP1? Can we upgrade to from Tridion 2013 to Tridion 2013 SP1 without conflict?

Comment: If Quirijn's method does work, let us know!

Comment: I'm currently waiting for the Tridion 2013SP1 installation files from Tridion Customer Support. Will let you know when I find out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2013 provider will most likely break if it encounters a Tridion DLL with a different version.

There are two solutions:

- Build the project against the 2013 SP1 DLLs as Rob suggests (and please give it back to the community!)
- Redirect the Tridion assemblies from 2013 GA to 2013 SP1, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.

Answer (score 4):

The upgrade from 2011 sp1 to 2013 just meant rebuilding against the right Content Delivery DLLs and I would think the same applies for 2013 sp1.

It should only be the Provider DLL you need to change really. I would say try and create the provider and give back to the community!

Comment: We're actually thinking of upgrading from 2013 to 2013 SP1. There are no providers, yes, but I thought it might just work with the 2013 providers.

Comment: It might work, but as Quirjin said the problem is the version numbers of the Content Delivery DLLs have changed from 7.0 to 7.1 so .NET will not like the switch by default to protect from subtle bugs and mismatched methods.

Answer (score 3):

I hit a few compatibility issues with this this week and I've created a NuGet package which contains a version of the Tridion 2013 providers with updated references to the SP1 DLLs here:

http://nuget.org/packages/DD4T-Tridion-2013sp1/

For the time being, this will just replace the 2013 provider with updated references; however, I've requested write access to the DD4T codebase and will update the package with an independent SP1 assembly ASAP. This should do the trick in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

For the java version, there will be an updated provider jar next week if it doesn't simply work anyway.